# How to run an existed language server without vscode

Tags: node.js, typescript, language-server-protocol

I am trying to develop my own IDE with language server protocol support, so i download language server written in typescript and try to start them with Node.js.
First, I packaged the server package with webpack. and then start with the command "node server.js", server.js is produced by webpack. but I got

```
Error: Connection input stream is not set. Use arguments of createConnection or set command line parameters: '--node-ipc', '--stdio' or '--socket={number}'
at D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:172642
at t.createConnection (D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:179222)
at Object.999 (D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:72865)
at n (D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:186299)
at D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:186653
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\vscode-autohotkey2-lsp\server\dist\server.js:1:186661)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
```

then I followed the Error information, replaced the command with "node server.js --node-ipc". the error above didn't appear again, but i didn't got a server process in my Windows task manager.
I am new to typescript and language-server-protocol, did I got sth wrong or misunderstand sth?

Comment: Hello, did you have find any answer to this question?

Comment: you can also run the language server in the terminal with the `--stdio` flag
e.g. `vscode-eslint-language-server --stdio`